# Storing list of times and sorting as ascending

Tags: list, sorting, time

I am using C# .Net 4

I have a list of times in seconds, up to 600 (10 min), In the format of ##.###, Currently I am gathering these into a List string and then using .Sort()

Here is an example of what I am getting when I write it to a txt file

```
193.225 193.225 88

195.489 195.489 89

197.741 197.741 90

199.993 199.993 91

2.334   2.334   2

20.213  20.213  13

202.246 202.246 92

204.51  204.51  93

206.762 206.762 94
```

I need help finding an easy way to put these in the correct order, I do nothing I can use List int because of the tab that seperates each field.

Here is my current code

```
    private void ExportMarkCollections(MarkCollection collection, string exportType)
    {
        if (exportType == "vixen3")
        {
            foreach (MarkCollection mc in MarkCollections)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", mc.Name));

                mymarks = "";
                foreach (TimeSpan time in mc.Marks)
                {
                    mymarks = mymarks + time;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", mymarks));
            }
        }

        if (exportType == "audacity")
        {
            List<string> BeatMarks = new List<string>();
            iMarkCollection = 0;
            foreach (MarkCollection mc in MarkCollections)
            {
                iMarkCollection++;
                foreach (TimeSpan time in mc.Marks)
                {
                    BeatMarks.Add(time.TotalSeconds + "\t" + time.TotalSeconds + "\t" + iMarkCollection);
                    if (MarkCollections.Count == 1)
                        iMarkCollection++;
                }
            }
            BeatMarks.Sort();

            string filter = "Audacity Marks (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = filter;
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string name = saveFileDialog.FileName;

                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(name))
                {
                    foreach (string bm in BeatMarks)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(bm);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think we need more information. Which language is your target? What have you done until now? The last column is not in format ##.###, is that important? Which column shall be sorted, or do you expect only one column in the end instead of three? What have you tried so far and what is your current output? What is the expected output?

Comment: You either need to put leading zeros in the numeric strings, or separate them as numbers and sort them that way.

Comment: Target language is C# .Net 4, Currently I populate the List and use .Sort, This is the output I have now. The last column is as it should be, and the first column is the one it should be sorted by. The expected output is as shown, but in proper order.

Answer (score 0):

Mike's comment is correct. You can, for example, do this (note - no error handling in this code!):

```
    public static int CompareStrings(string a, string b)
    {
        double x = double.Parse(a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf('\t')));
        double y = double.Parse(b.Substring(0, a.IndexOf('\t')));
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
```

and then:

```
    list.Sort(CompareStrings);
```

However, I would suggest *not throwing the numbers into a tab delimited string* in the first place. Data should be kept in as "clean" format as possible until the last moment (for example, until display in the UI), otherwise you're just making things harder on yourself (you have to worry about regional settings, decimal dot vs comma, etc). Consider these potential problems if the file you're outputting will be read on a different machine / by a different application.